# Do I need USART1 to program the bootloader with STM32 - Or could I use SWDIO & SWCLK?

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I have heard that if I buy an empty factory made STM32, it will come with no bootloader at all. To program that STM32 with a bootloader, I need to do that through USART1. And later when I want to implement the program onto the STM32, I need to use SWDIO & SWCLK.

Is that correct? Or could I program the bootloader with USART1 and SWDIO & SWCLK, the same way I can program the STM32 with USART1 and SWDIO & SWCLK as well?

Comment: Where did you hear that? Simply not true and easy to check from the datasheet.

Comment: swd us thus far supported on all cortex-ms used by st.  The usart based bootloader is in some form, thus far, supported on all of the stm32s, but the writing is on the wall based on the newer parts that that may be going away as you get one shot at it and then the bootloader itself is no longer available much less the uart1 interface to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STM32 will come with factory bootloader. That bootloader is the one that enables programming over various interfaces if SWD or JTAG is not used. Different models support different interfaces, but UART1 is always supported.

You can always use the SWD and JTAG interfaces as they do not even need to run bootloader code for that to work.

Comment: Ok. Can I use USART1 to communicate with Raspberry Pi too? Or do I need to use another USART if I want UART communication?

Comment: Why would you need to use another UART for that? You can even update the STM32 firmware from RasPi if you connect it to a UART that is supported by the factory bootloader, just boot into bootloader and run a flashing program on RasPi.

Comment: I want to use my ST-Link to burn in programs and then I want to use USART1 to communicate with Raspberry Pi. I'm using STM32CubeMXIDE.

Comment: Yes, nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: Great! I don't know why people say that I cannot use USART1 for communication.

Comment: What people? Where? Perhaps you told them something I don't know. Like which STM32 and which board is it on?

Comment: This is just a STM32 F3 serie. But they told that USART1 is only for bruning the bootloader. So if I use USART1 for bootloader and also for communicating with external unit, e.g Raspberry's TX and RX pins.

Comment: But in this case, if the bootloader is already there, I'm only need the ST-Link programmer to program the STM32.

Comment: F3 series has dozens of different MCU models, all different from each others and bootloader capabilities so that tells nothing. But those people are simply wrong, and if they claim so they should have some proof to back that up. All USARTs can be used for USART comms. Only some of them are special that the internal bootloader can use them, as the bootloader does not support every USART.

Comment: I understand that USART1 is the default standard for programming STM32 with the USB cable. But in this case I'm only using ST-Link V2 as in STM32CubeMXIDE.

Comment: Now a surprise USB cable? How does now USB cable come into picture? Some STM32 chips can be programmed with USB using the bootloader, but you must be talking about a USB UART cable? UART1 is the standard bootloader interface regardless of where it connects and how.

Comment: Sorry! I'm mean USART. Not USB.

Comment: The uart programming interface is no longer "always supported".  The newer parts (stm32g and others) have security and only a virgin part a part with an erased vector table will support the uart interface, after that by default you can no longer get in that way you have to use swd.  You can change the non-volatile registers to allow the uart interface after the fact but the default is becoming one shot and no more.  Other companies are abandoning their bootloader if they had one.  so just saying be careful with words like "always" and "never"...

Comment: And yes of course, the bootloader is just a program no different than yours other than who wrote it and where it is stored.  You can use usart1 all day long, nothing prevents you from using it...

Comment: with the stm32's you have to provide more of the part number, st has multiple choices for peripherals and for  reasons not obvious will pick and choose, this stm32 uses this uart, that one uses the other, this one uses this gpio, that one uses the other.  these seven have the uart at this address, but these seven are at a mixture of other addresses, etc.  some mcus you can simply say blah and we know it, but most in particular from st you need more of the part number than stm32f3 to talk about it...